# use for loop to generate different combination of alphabet

Tags: java, for-loop

```
static void generator7(String fileName) throws IOException {

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
    String[] list = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

    for (int o = 0; o < list.length; o++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < list.length; m++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < list.length; l++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                                fw.append(list[i] + list[j] + list[k]
                                        + list[l] + list[m] + list[n]
                                        + list[o]);
                                fw.append("\n");

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have this code I use to generate different combination of alphabet(a,b,c,d). I expect it to generate aaaaaaa, aaaaaac, aaaaaag, aaaaaat to ttttttt. However, the combination generated stop at tttttgt. No exception throws. I have no idea which part of my code went wrong. Please help.

```
static void generator7(String fileName) throws IOException {

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
String[] list = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

for (int o = 0; o < list.length; o++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < list.length; m++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < list.length; l++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                            fw.append(list[i] + list[j] + list[k]
                                    + list[l] + list[m] + list[n]
                                    + list[o]);
                            fw.append("\n");

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
fw.flush();
fw.close();

}
```

Edited : 1st code is the problem. 2nd code is the solution.

Comment: You should consider using recursion for this.

Comment: take some time and explain your question.I mean show your expection and result.

Comment: @var___: Isn't that at the bottom of the question?

Comment: @Blender i know, but it is totally messed and that's why i said, take some time.

Comment: will try on recursion some other time. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're not flushing the `FileWriter`. The remaining strings are almost certainly in memory still and not yet written to disk. Make sure you flush and close the `FileWriter` when you are done with it.

In fact, only calling the `close` method is strictly necessary, because it calls `flush` itself, but since you've been caught out by the lack of flush, thought it was important to highlight here...